# Counting (Stars and Bars)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm currently preparing for my final in discrete mathematics and encountered what appears to be a stars and bars problem. The problem is framed as follows:

> *A bowl containing hard candies has 50 cherry pieces, 50 strawberry pieces, 40 orange pieces, and 70 pineapple pieces. All pieces of a flavor are identical. You grab 15 pieces of candy.*

The aspect I'm finding challenging is:

> *How many different handfuls are possible?*

I came across a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368230/bowl-containing-candy-how-many-handfuls-of-15-are-possible-with-extra-conditio) on a forum, but one of the answers involves generating functions, a topic we haven't covered in class, and the top response was a bit unclear.

According to the answer key provided by my professor, the solution is:

$$C(18,15) = 816$$

I'm curious to understand where this comes from, especially since the answer on the forum is different:

$$C(19,4)=3876$$

Could someone please explain how to approach and solve this problem? I'm familiar with binomial coefficients but am unsure about the origin of the number 18 in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the number of candies of each flavor is greater than or equal to the size of the handful, the amounts in the bowl don't matter.

So you have $4$ choices of flavor, and you want to count how many ways you can select $15$ out of the $4$ possibilities, with repetitions allowed. That's a classic stars-and-bars/combinations-with-repetitions problem. To compute the number of ways of making $k$ choices out of $n$ possibilities with repetitions allowed and where order does not matter is given by
$$\binom{n+k-1}{k}.$$
That's what you professor gave.

The problem you point to is different, because there you have **five**, not four, flavors available (cherry, strawberry, orange, ***lemon***, and pineapple; your problem does not have lemon flavored candy). That's why the answer is different there. (Also, the first, accepted answer does *not* use generating functions, so you were not paying very much attention in that post...)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Just to make sure, my `n` would be 15 (size of handful) and my `k` would be 4 (number of flavours)? When would we consider `n` to be the sum of the candies in the bowl and `k` to be "amount getting picked"

Comment: I know the first one does not use generating functions, but the second one does. The first answer wasn't very clear as I am struggling with discrete mathematics at this very moment.

Comment: @Jakob: What's unclear about the first answer? You have 19 places where you can say "no", and you need to pick the $4$ places where you say "no". So that's $\binom{19}{4}$ ways of making those choices. Also, your post says "The answerS involve generating functions." There are two answers, only one of which involves generating functions. So your post is inaccurate.

Comment: I apologise, I was unclear in my question. I will edit it accordingly. And as I mentioned I am struggling with combinatorics and I have a final coming up next week.

Comment: @Jakob See also [this Stars and Bars article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this Stars and Bars article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).